# The right way to define an operation that computes the absolute value

Tags: c++

I have a simple class for working with some column/row coordinates that have `+` and `-` operators:

```
class CellCoord
{
public:

    CellCoord() : CellCoord(-1, -1)
    {

    }

    CellCoord(int col, int row) : Column(col), Row(row)
    {
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        *this = CellCoord();
    }

    operator bool() const
    {
        return Column != -1;
    }

    CellCoord operator- () const
    {
        return { -Column, -Row };
    }

    CellCoord operator+ (const CellCoord& other)  const
    {
        return { Column + other.Column, Row + other.Row };
    }

    CellCoord operator- (const CellCoord& other)  const
    {
        return { Column - other.Column, Row - other.Row };
    }

    CellCoord& operator+= (const CellCoord& other)
    {
        *this = *this + other;

        return *this;
    }

    CellCoord& operator-= (const CellCoord& other)
    {
        *this = *this - other;

        return *this;
    }

    int Column;

    int Row;
};
```

What is the right way to define an operation that computes the absolute value of a `CellCoord` that is `CellCoord{std::abs(other.Column), std::abs(other.Row)}`?

Should I define a member function or overload `std::abs` like this?

```
namespace std
{
    CellCoord abs(const CellCoord& coord)
    {
        return {std::abs(other.Column), std::abs(other.Row)};
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to define your own overloads in `std`

Comment: @JesperJuhl what do you mean?

Comment: @NathanOliver "You are not allowed to define your own overloads in std" - generally correct, but there are exceptions to that rule (to allow template specialization for example).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Actually that was removed in C++ 20 as well.  Also, a specialization is not an overload, so the rule still holds.

Comment: I would simplify the constructor:  `CellCoord(int r = -1, int c = -1) : Row(r), Column(c) { ; }`.

Comment: Your `operator-()` can result in a negative Column or Row value.  Need to check before modifying the member values.

Comment: You may want to make the `Row` and `Column` members private so external entities don't make their values negative.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the usual way of defining addition and subtraction is to provide `operator+=` and `operator-=` as member functions (since they modify the object), and to write `operator+` and `operator-` as non-member functions that call `+=` and `-=`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Should I specialize `std::numeric_limits` in C++20 if I define my own arithmetic-like type, for example `decimal` or something like `boost::int256_t`?